# Detailed background 9patch

Tags: android, graphics, nine-patch

I have a detailed background that has a hole in it (transparent area in the middle). The background is detailed png image. 
Now I want this hole to be shown on all devices equally. So I thought of 9patch, but then the details get screwed of the image. If I don't use 9patch, the hole appears as an egg, which is not the point.

What is the way to fix this?

**update**

[image]

Comment: r u creating 9-patch correctly ?

Comment: Have you used the 9 patch tool that comes with the SDK? You'll find it where ever you installed and Android SDK.

Comment: yes, I am creating it correctly. but it's distorting the background because the background has lots of gradients and staff on it. And it looks bad.

Comment: Upload your image please. What is the filename for the image?

Answer (score 0):

I used 2 different methods (depending on what is better in the excact case)
-different resources for different screens.
   -Disadvantage: will increase you app size significantly
   -Advantage: This is quit convenient for you to use

-Extend Drawable and give your Background and a alpha map (Alphamap in your case would be a ninepatch with 0xffffffff ouside and 0x00ffffff as color for your circle) over with the constructor. 
Override draw(). Create 
ComposeShader(
    drawable1,
    drawable2,
    PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
Set the shader to a paint and draw it on the canvas.

-Disadvantage: Not so convenient
   -keeps you app size small :)

Comment: Sorry for not more info / formating. Only crappy mobile :9 Maybe in 2 days I am back home and can provide you code.

Comment: I have edited the question with my picture. What is the appropriate way to create 9patch from this?